# Can't change the PaperSize & Orientation properties of the Excel's PageSetup class from VB.net

Tags: vb.net, excel, vba

I'm trying to change paper size and sheet orientation of Excel worksheet,
Code runs without any errors, but nothing changes in Excel

Here a code:

```
Private Sub doCompare()
  Dim xlApp As Excel.Application = Nothing
  Dim DEs As Excel.Worksheet = Nothing
  Dim Rws As Excel.Worksheet = Nothing
  Dim ewb As Excel.Workbook = Nothing

  XLapp = New Excel.Application
  ewb = XLapp.Workbooks.Open("xxxxxxx0.xls")
  DEs = ewb.Worksheets("Data Entry")
  Rws = ewb.Worksheets("Comparing Results")

  'Do something with these worksheets

  'Now trying to change default settings. Code copied from Excel macro
  xlApp.PrintCommunication = False
  Rws.PageSetup.PrintArea = ""
  DEs.PageSetup.PrintArea = ""
  With Rws.PageSetup
     .Orientation = Excel.XlPageOrientation.xlLandscape
     .PaperSize = Excel.XlPaperSize.xlPaperA4
     .FitToPagesWide = 1     'Fit All Columns to page
  End With
  xlApp.PrintCommunication = True

End Sub
```

Printer driver is installed

Comment: Solution found! At first, `Rws.PageSetup.PrintArea = ""` must be before of `xlApp.PrintCommunication = False` an second, changes must be applied for **ALL** worksheets in the workbook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Maxim Tried your code and it is working. Keep in mind that based on your code, you're changing the page setup ONLY for worksheet "Comparing Results". "Data Entry" remains unchanged.

-Feel free to upvote if answer is correct.

Comment: Did you try to step into your code? Add a breakpoint on .Orientation and see if the code really passes that line. One of the possibilities I'm thinking is a misplaced Try-Catch somewhere on your "'Do something with these worksheets"

Comment: Solution found! At first,  
    Rws.PageSetup.PrintArea = ""
must be before of
    xlApp.PrintCommunication = False
an second, changes must be applied for ALL worksheets in the workbook.
Thank you!